# Where is my error in using generating functions to solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $T(n)=2T(n-1)+n$, $T(1)=1$. It is known that $T(n) = 2^{n+1}-(n+2)$. However, my attempt yields something different: let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)z^n$ and sum both sides of the recurrence over $n\geqslant1$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(n)z^n = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(n-1)z^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n 
$$
or
$$
f(z) - T(1) = 2zf(z) +\frac z{(1-z)^2},
$$
hence
$$f(z) = \frac1{1-2z} + \frac z{(1-2z)(1-z)^2}.
$$
Partial fraction decomposition yields
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac1{1-2z} + \frac2{1-2z}-\frac1{1-z}-\frac1{(1-z)^2}\\
&= \frac3{1-2z}-\frac1{1-z}-\frac1{(1-z)^2}\\
&= 3\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nz^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (3\cdot 2^n - (n+2))z^n.
\end{align}
Somehow I have a factor of $3$ that is not in the correct expression. Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand side of your second displayed equation should be $f(z)-T(0)$, not $f(z)-T(1)$. If you correct that error through to the end you will indeed end up with $2^{n+1}-(n+2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was something as trivial as that, but I simply could not see it!

Comment: You were probably looking at all the hard stuff, which you got right!